# Enfore SF iOS and Android App Updated\s

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

Is there a way within SF to enforce or verfiy that all users have the latest version of the SF app?
Or does SF handle this themselves?

We want to make sure we have the highest level of security if users are using the SF app.

(Any SF documentation will be appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this finally! 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_requirements.htm&type=5

Says its required- and implemented! Good news!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.